# webdriver: request failed due to response error: unknown error when running WebdriverIO tests in Safari 16

Tags: webdriver-io

The Tests are running fine in other browsers. When running the test in Safari browser version 16 (Mac OS - Ventura 13.3) I am getting below error

webdriver: request failed due to response error: unknown error
Request failed with status 500 due to unknown error
unknown error: unknown error
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Browser is initiated and Login works fine. Post login, getting this error when validating the tester or clicking on element etc.

**Capabilities**:

platformName:'Mac',
browserName: 'safari',
browserVersion: '16.4',

export const config: Options.Testrunner = {
protocol: 'http',
hostname: 'localhost',
path: '/',
port: 4444,
services: [
['safaridriver', {
outputDir: './logs',
logFileName: 'wdio-safaridriver.log'
}]
],
autoCompileOpts: {
autoCompile: true,
tsNodeOpts: {
transpileOnly: true,
project: './tsconfig.json'
}
}

**Versions:
**"wdio-safaridriver-service": "^2.1.1",
"webdriverio": "^7.32.3"
"selenium-webdriver": "^4.10.0",
"@wdio/cli": "^7.32.3",
"@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^7.32.3",
"@wdio/local-runner": "^7.32.3",
"npm": "^8.7.0",

I have the option enabled "Allow Remote Automation" in Safari browser.

Additionally it seems the issue when page is reloaded. Here post login , Home page is loaded and when finding elements in the Home page, it throws error.

Please note the tests are working fine in Chrome, Firefox and Edge browser.

Expecting the tests to run in Safari